# How to access dynamically created element (JAVA)?

Tags: java, swing

I have dynamically created several jCheckBox elements:

```
for (j=0;j<j1;j++){
   final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("");
   cb.setText(col_name);
   mainPanel12.add(cb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   mainPanel12.repaint();
...
}
```

How can i access some particular checkboxes outside the loop as they all have the same name **cb**?

Comment: Sidenote: you will only add 1 checkbox (the last) to your panel since a `BorderLayout` can only contain one or zero elements in each region. So when you add an element to the NORTH, you will remove the previous added element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one HashMap of Integer and jCheckBox like this outside for loop as intance variable:

```
Map<Integer,JCheckBox> map = new HashMap<Integer,JCheckBox>();
for (j=0;j<j1;j++){
   final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("");
   cb.setText(col_name);
   mainPanel12.add(cb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   mainPanel12.repaint();
   map.put(j,cb);
...
}
```

outside loop you can use like this;

```
JCheckBox = map.get(index_value_of_checkbox);
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i<map.size(); ++i)
JCheckBox cb = map.get(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

That variable name is only accessible within the loop, so it would be of no use anyway. Have you considered member variables in the class in which you call this piece of code? An array of JCheckBoxes, if necessary.

Comment: How to create an array ofJCheckBoxes?

Comment: With respect, that's fundamental Java coding - they can be declared as an array just like declaring an array of *any* data type. May I recommend looking at some tutorials? For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to [get the components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) from the panel mainPanel12 and iterate over the collection. You can set a name to your component and then try to search for a component with that name.

```
for (j=0;j<j1;j++){
   final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("");
   cb.setText(col_name);
   cb.setName(String.toString(j);
   mainPanel12.add(cb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   mainPanel12.repaint();
...
}

Component[] comps = mainPanel12.getComponents();
for (j=0;j<mainPanel12.size();j++){
   Component c = comps[i];
   if("1".equals(c.getName())) {
       // and here is your component :-)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data structure outside the loop in order to record each value of cb as you create new objects.  The easiest way would be to have a container of some sort (perhaps an array or java.util.List) that will contain all of the checkboxes:

```
JCheckBox[] cbs=new JCheckBox[j1];

for (j=0;j<j1;j++)   {
    final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("");
    cb.setText(col_name);
    mainPanel12.add(cb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel12.repaint();

    ...

    cbs[j]=cb;
}
```

Now you can refer to checkboxes by indexing elements of the array outside the loop.